# Is there a better design for exposing a base interface you don't want directly implemented?

Tags: c#

I am creating an API that allows someone to build out a menu with selectable options. The API library itself doesn't have any rendering logic, just the info needed to describe the options. That way, an consumer of this API can add it as a dependency, and a renderer library can add it as a dependency. Then the renderer can render a menu based on the objects created by the consumer.

It is something like this:

```
public interface IOptionGroup
{
    List<IOption> Options { get; }
}

public interface IOption
{
    //Some Shared attributes for all Options
}

public interface IOptionCheckbox : IOption
{
    // Some checkbox specific attributes
    void OnValueChanged(bool newValue);
}
```

**Exposing the Base Interface:**

Having the base IOption interface is nice because it holds all the shared attributes of all the different Option types, but it only makes sense for the user of the API to implement interfaces derived from IOption. If they implemented IOption itself and passed it back as one of the Options, there would not be enough information to actually draw a valid Option to the menu.

**Upcasting During Rendering:**

Furthermore, this design forces me upcast the interfaces to determine which Option type to render (which doesn't feel right). Also, what if they implement multiple Option interfaces?!?

```
foreach(IOption option in group.Options) 
{
    if (option is IOptionCheckbox) 
    {
        // Render a Checkbox
    } else if (option is ...)
    {
       // Render a ...
    }
}
```

**Use Case to Make it clearer:**

I want the client to be able to implement the interfaces describing the menu items without having to know anything about rendering them. For different options they get difference callbacks:

Example Client Code:

```
public class MyCheckBox : IOptionCheckbox
{
    void OnValueChanged(bool newValue)
    {
        // Do something specific here when user checks/unchecks option
    }
}
```

The client only has to worry about what to do when the Checkbox is clicked. I can't put a Renderer in the IOption interface since that would require the client to implement the rederer themselves.

Comment: "*...there would not be enough information to actually draw a valid Option to the menu.*" Point this out in the documentation and throw an exception when this happens. The API user will quickly learn. The other option is an abstract base class, but I assume you prefer interfaces.

Comment: @DanWilson Abstract base class is an interesting idea, but I suppose they could just inherit the base class and pass it in (I wouldn't be able to have abstract methods for all information required to draw an option, because they would depend on which Option you are drawing). Perhaps the documentation is the way to go.

Comment: Sounds like you could benefit from using `Dictionary<Type, List<IOption>> Options` and grouping options by type. A custom logic could be used on how things are added to this dictionary with a type check, smth like: `if(newOption.GetType() == typeof(IOption)) throw new ArgumentException("...there would not be enough information to actually draw a valid Option to the menu.")`   (msg as @DanWilson has kindly suggested)

Comment: @Fabjan I am not setup to try this suggestion at the moment, but will GetType return an interface type of an object? I would have assumed it returns the underlying concrete type.

Comment: @Aaron No, it will return the concrete type

Comment: @Fabjan Perhaps I'm just not understanding what you mean, but would that mean this line wouldn't work? `if(newOption.GetType() == typeof(IOption))` As a class implementing IOption wouldn't have concrete type of IOption

Comment: The fact that `IOption` doesn't have enough for you to use it, and the fact that you're casting to derived types means that the interface is missing operations that ought to be on it.  The interface should provide all of what you need in order to render it, and different implementations should override whatever members may be needed in order to render themselves.

Comment: @Servy I agree with what you are saying, it is just that there is no way to rendor an IOption without knowing the type of Option it is. For instance, there is an IOptionButton that renders a Button with a clickable button component. There is an IOptionCheckBox that renders an Option with a checkbox. Theoretically the missing method is simply rendor(), however that isn't something that should be implemented by the consumer of the API and so can't be in the interface.

Comment: Consider using the pattern used by the framework to accomplish this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.renderer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What about [Explicit Interface Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)? For instance, `System.Int32` structure has explicit interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't come up with a perfect way to do exactly what I wanted, but I will split my answer into two options with pros and cons of each. If you are seeking a solution to a similar problem of your own, you probably want to go with option 1.

---

### Option 1: Good Interfaces

The major issue here (as @Servy pointed out) is that interfaces should really contain every operation necessary to perform their intended purpose. What that looks like for the above example could be something like this:

```
public interface IRenderer
{
    void Draw(/* Params needed to draw */);
}

public interface IOption
{
    //Some Shared attributes for all Options
    IRenderer Renderer { get; }
}
```

The rendering library could then provide (possibly abstract) implementations of interfaces that derive from IOption that the client could use to render options, or inherit from and override or simply instantiate and use.

#### Renderer Code:

```
public abstract class RendererOptionCheckbox : IOptionCheckbox
{
    public IRenderer Renderer => new CheckboxRender();

    public abstract void OnValueChanged(bool newValue);
}
```

#### Client Code:

```
public class MyCheckBox : RendererOptionCheckbox
{
    void OnValueChanged(bool newValue)
    {
        // Do something specific here when user checks/unchecks option
    }
}
```

#### Pros:

- No need to upcast to Render a list of IOption as each option knows how to rendor itself
- No problem with exposing base IOption interface as the Renderer would have to be defined if a client tried to use it
- A client could inject their own custom IOption with custom rendering logic

#### Cons:

- A client could inject their own custom IOption with custom rendering logic (this is a double edge sword, you may not want this)
- Client would need to instantiate objects inherited directly from the renderer, making the coupling between the actual renderer and client a little tighter than I want.

---

### Option 2: Document Your Issues

Just write the code as described in the original problem, use upcasting to perform the rendering, throw a detailed exception if IOption is implemented directly, and provide good documentation of valid use vs invalid use of the classes (as @DanWilson suggested).

#### Pros:

- Clean interface from clients perspective (no rendering logic in sight)

  - Client can use interface without worrying about which related renderer specific classes to instantiate or inherit from
  - Easy to swap renderers without changing client code at all

#### Cons:

- upcasting to render a list of IOptions (yuck!)
- IOption is exposed but not directly usable (confusing)